# Failed to start a parallel pool using the 'local' profile in MATLAB MapReducer 2014b

Tags: matlab, hadoop, parallel-processing, mapreduce

I am using an example from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/compute-mean-value-with-mapreduce.html) as "Compute Mean Value with MapReduce" in MATLAB 2014b. When I run the example, the below error comes:

> Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'local' profile ...  Error
>   using mapreducer (line 96) Failed to start a parallel pool. (For
>   information in addition to the causing error, validate the profile
>   'local' in the Cluster Profile Manager.)
>
> Error in gcmr (line 34)
>       mr = mapreducer();
>
> Error in mapreduce (line 94)
>       mrcer = gcmr();
>
> Error in MapReduceFunction (line 10) meanDelay = mapreduce(ds,
>   @Mapper1, @Reducer1);
>
> Caused by:
>       Error using parallel.internal.pool.InteractiveClient/start (line 329)
>       Failed to start pool.
>           Error using parallel.Job/submit (line 304)
>           All dimension arguments must be greater than zero

I checked the 'local' profile which has some problems as follows in the figure:

[image: error in 'local' profile]

How we can fix the problem?

Comment: I would recommend you [contact MathWorks technical support](http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/?s_tid=sp_ban_cs)

If you just want to try out MapReduce without the Parallel Computing Toolbox, you can use `mapreducer(0)` which will run the code without PCT.

Comment: If I use `mapreducer(0)`, does it effect negatively on the performance? What is the strengths and weak points of shutting down the PCT?

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it's a software installation problem.

Comment: @Edric , This problem is related to software developing/programming. So, it is unfair to give a negative point to my question. Please, try to help to solve the problem in order to fill a gap for software developers who work with MATLAB MapReducer.

Comment: @BlueBit the problem is entirely with your installation - that's why Tom suggested you contact MathWorks technical support. Your reproduction steps do not exhibit any problem on a correctly-functioning installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `mapreducer(0)` only negatively affects the performance for large problems. This setting basically tells `mapreduce` to use only your local MATLAB session to process the data, so for small problems this works out to be quicker than the overhead required for running in parallel. This simple example problem is one such case.

See this page in the PCT doc for more info:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-mapreduce-on-a-local-cluster.html

Comment: Perfect. This is the answer I searched. (1) Can we declare some global parameters in the main function, and call them in Reducer? Or all the parameters that are used in the Reducer, should call from Mapper? (2) Also, Can some workers in mapper session do extra tasks? Or all the worker should do a same task?

Comment: (1) There are some examples in the MATLAB documentation showing how to parameterize the map and/or reduce functions to pass in extra parameters. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/build-effective-algorithms-with-mapreduce.html

(2) I don't know of a way to make different mappers do different tasks. In MATLAB each call to the map function by mapreduce is a map task, so the only thing that changes is the data being passed in. You'd have to use several calls to mapreduce with different map functions on different extents of the data in order to accomplish what you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

After working on MATLAB and fixing the problem, I found a solution. There are different reasons to occur this validation error. One of the solution is as follows:

> (1) Run the following MATLAB commands in order:
>
> **rehash toolboxcache;**
>
> **restoredefaultpath;**
>
> **savepath**
>
> (2) Restart MATLAB and try the validation again.